# Measuring distance from coast along stream network

Tags: arcgis-pro, distance, network, proximity, stream

I have a stream network I am using to make a suitability model for a species. One of the factors I want to consider is distance from a given point to the coast, so I'm hoping to find a way to create a raster showing the distance to the coast for each cell. One thing I've tried is distance accumulation with a barriers input where every cell that isn't a stream is considered a barrier. This produced straight lines protruding outward from the coast.

1. I think the issue could've been that the streams layer extends slightly past the coast. The only accurate coastline I've been able to find is a polyline, so I was wondering if anyone knew how to clip a raster based on a single polyline as opposed to a polygon or outline/closed polyline.
2. It's possible this wasn't even the issue, though. Are there any other ways to do this distance analysis along the streams to produce the raster?

I'm using ArcGIS Pro.